# Local variable min defined in an enclosing scope must be final or effectively final

Tags: java

My problem appears in a recursive method. Here is the code:

```
    public static Pair<Integer, Integer> ejercicio9(Tree<Integer> tree) {
    Pair<Integer, Integer> t = null; 
    if(tree.getType()!=TreeType.Empty) {
        t = ejercicio9(tree, tree.getLabel(), tree.getLabel());
    }
    return t;
}

public static Pair<Integer, Integer> ejercicio9(Tree<Integer> tree, int min, int max) {
    int label = tree.getLabel();
    Pair<Integer, Integer> t = Pair.of(null, null);
    switch(tree.getType()) {
    case Empty:
        break;
    case Leaf:
        if(min>label) { 
            min = label;
        } else if (max<label) {
            max = label;
        } else if(min==label) {
            min = label;
        } else if(max==label) {
            max = label;
        }
        break;
    case Nary:
        tree.getChildren().stream().map(arbol -> ejercicio9(arbol,min,max)); //the error appears here
        break;
    }
    t = Pair.of(min, max);
    return t;
}
```

I'm trying with this code to search the min value and the max value of a tree.

Comment: You cannot use a non-final variable inside an anonymous class and update it elsewhere.

Comment: The easy fix is to declare `final int fMin = min, fMax = max;` just before the stream, and then use those in the lambda. But it's not clear what you're expecting to happen as a result of doing `map` on that stream.